# What is the proper way to do for each where in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have these 2 functions below. I want to change `$report->rate` to count of results. So total rows from this query `foreach($campaign->reports->where('status', 2)` so if there is 10 results that's true it will be `$total_cap = $total_cap + 10;`

```
public static function checkTotalCap(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $total_cap = 0;
    foreach($campaign->reports->where('status', 2) as $report)
    {
        $total_cap = $total_cap + $report->rate;
    }

    if($campaign->cap <= $total_cap)
        return true;

    return false;
}

public static function checkDailyCap(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $daily_cap = 0;
    foreach($campaign->reports->where('status', 2) as $report)
    {
        if($report->created_at->isToday())
        {
            $daily_cap = $daily_cap + $report->rate;
        }
    }

    if($campaign->daily_cap <= $daily_cap)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This is how its used

```
if($campaign->cap !== 0)
        {
            // Check if total cap or daily cap reached
            if($this->checkTotalCap($campaign) || $this->checkDailyCap($campaign))
            {
                $campaign->active = 'no';
                $campaign->save();
                return "The campaign has reached its cap.";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not how foreach() works. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EriksKlotins foreach($campaign->reports as $report WHERE status == "2") Im trying to count reports with status of 2.

Comment: You can't add a `WHERE` clause to a `foreach()`; you need the results first. Why not `$campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->count()`??? Alternatively, if your need the `foreach()` loop, the answers below show how to apply a `where()` clause to your `$campaign->reports()` relationship **before** using it in the loop.

Comment: @TimLewis im not following, Above is how my script currently does it I have checkDailyCap working as I need but I need help on other one. Site was made with laravel 5

Comment: How is that unclear? If you want a count of the `reports` that have a `status` of `2`, you do `$campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->count()`. If you want the `foreach()` loop, see the answers below. Laravel version is irrelevant here; that code hasn't changed, and the rest is basic PHP structures, which won't change.

Comment: Also, if one is working, maybe try to copy replicate it for the one that is not working. Notice how your working one has an `if()` statement and the non-working one doesn't? There's a reason for that...

Comment: @TimLewis this did it for me `foreach($campaign->reports as $report)` to `foreach($campaign->reports->where('status', 2) as $report)` you added count

Comment: Again, read my comment; if you just needed the count, like your comment says: *"Im trying to count reports with status of 2"*, then you'd use mine. If you need to use the `foreach()` on them, then use one of the answers below; they are both much more efficient than your solution.

Comment: @TimLewis How would I implement your way into my functions above? I have those 2 functions above

Comment: See my answer below; you don't need these `foreach()` loops at all; just use SQL-level functions `WHERE ... SUM(...)` and compare against the `$campaign->cap`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this pretty simply

```
$reports = $campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->whereDate('created_at', now())->get();

foreach($reports as $report)
{
   $daily_cap = $daily_cap + $report->rate;
}
```

Write separate query with conditions and simply loop it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to filter the reports with status == 2 and:

```
$reports = $campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->get();

foreach($reports as $report) {
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed `foreach($campaign->reports as $report)` to `foreach($campaign->reports->where('status', 2) as $report)`

Comment: @Varri The code in this answer is actually much more efficient than your commented answer. I suggest you try to use this instead. Theirs is doing a DB-level filter, while yours needs to load _everything_ into memory first, then a PHP-level filter, which can be inefficient for large datasets.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes exactly!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `foreach()` loops at all here:

```php
public static function checkTotalCap(Campaign $campaign) {
  return $campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->count() > $campaign->cap;
  // OR
  // $campaign->cap <= return $campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->count();
}

public static function checkDailyCap(Campaign $campaign) {
  return $campaign->reports()->where('created_at', Carbon::today())->where('status', 2)->count() > $campaign->daily_cap;
  // OR
  // return $campaign->daily_cap <= $campaign->reports()->where('created_at', Carbon::today())->where('status', 2)->count();
}
```

Use SQL-level queries to get the `SUM` of each Report's `rate` column, and compare against `$campaign->cap`.

Comment: But how can I implement this in place of my current code? I can't change much files or it may break other parts of the site. Seems it need to return true or false

Comment: I changed my question. I just noticed the developer im using is using + $report->rate instead of count of the results. How can I change it to he count of the results?

Comment: You implement that by replacing your code with mine... What are you talking about... I changed your code to this, and it ***does*** return `true` or `false`; `return ... <= ...` will be `true` or `false`... I think you need to learn some basics of PHP before trying to do whatever you're doing; I don't mean to be rude, but you do not have a grasp of the basic concepts, and you're going to struggle with anything above that basic level of understanding. Also, don't modify your question; there are already 3 answers to your old question, editing it invalidates them. Ask a new question please.

Comment: Ok your right im not a coder, currently learning. Also there was a mistake it should be `$daily_cap = $daily_cap + (where status is 2 Result count)` not `$daily_cap = $daily_cap + $report->rate;`. Basically I want to count all the results where status is 2. Then `if($campaign->daily_cap <= $daily_cap) return true;`

Comment: See my edit. If you just want `$daily_cap + (count of where status == 2)`, then you'd use `->count()` instead of `->sum('rate')`. `$campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->count()` is a one-liner than does the same thing as your entire `foreach()` loop, then instead of defining variables for them all, I just compare that via `<= $campaign->cap;`, which in the end still returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Ok I replaced my code with yours but it doesn't work. It doesn't provide an error it just does opposite of what I need. What I need is for it to check the reports table and count the results and check the number against the value I set in total cap and cap

Comment: If it's backwards or the opposite, then you probably just need to use `>` instead of `<=`; I might have got those backwards (see my edit). Alternatively, you could do some debugging and attempt to figure this out on your own. Use Laravel's `dd()` function to see what `$campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->count()` is compared to `$campaign->cap`: `dd($campaign->reports()->where('status', 2)->count())`, then `dd($campaign->cap)`; it should be pretty obvious then.

Comment: Just wanted to share this is how I solved it `public static function checkDailyCap(Campaign $campaign) {
        return Report::whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->where('campaign_id', $campaign->id)->where('status', 2)->count() >= $campaign->cap_daily;
    }
` The reason it wasn't working the way you shared is because it was searching for results for dates down to the second when it should only be y-m-d, so what was happening is it always returned 0 results